# How to close Iframe in c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I don't want to use target="_parent" in cshtml file. I want to close it from server side. i.e in C# action for redirect to a new window.

Currently it is opening in same Iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some effort I found this solution for above mentioned problem.

On successful Post, I have redirect to new View .cshtml and there in javascript.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var IframeModal = top.window.document.getElementById('myIframeModal');

        if ($(QuickAddUserModal).css('display') == "block") {
            parent.iFrameClose('#IframeModal');
        }

        if ('@Model.GoToUserRecordOnSave'=='False') {            
            parent.window.location.reload();
        }
        else {
            var url = '@Url.Action("ViewUser", "Users", new { id = Model.Id })';
            parent.window.location.href = url;
        }
    });
</script>
```

and there as you see ,First i have close Iframe and then redirected to new window which will not open in Iframe. That's work fine for me!